# How to call Cancel method of ActiveX control from FoxPro

Tags: activex, ole, visual-foxpro, foxpro, typelib

Visual Studio Object Explorer shows that upt.ocx has Cancel method:

[image: studio]

Visal Foxpo class is created based on this control.
Visual FoxPro properties window do not show Cancel method:

[image: vfp]

Callin upt.Cancel() in FoxPro throws error

```
Property Cancel is not a method or event
```

[image]

Callin ?upt.Cancel() throws error

```
Invalid subscript reference.
```

Other methods of this control can called OK.
Maybe name Cancel is used by FoxPro internally so that method with same name cannot called.

Using Object keyword

```
upt.Object.Cancel()
```

works. Is this best solution ?

Comment: Yes. This is the kind of situation that the Object keyword is designed for.

Comment: It is interesting that there is no Cancel() method in FoxPro classes. No idea why Cancel() call requires .object reference.

Comment: I don't know what this Cancel method does, but VFP classes don't need a Cancel method. What would it cancel?

Comment: This is upt.ocx method, not FoxPro method. I need to call ActiveX native Cancel method and its call without .object produces error. Other methods can called without using .object property

Comment: But Cancel is a VFP keyword. It's a property name for commandbuttons.